# How to find shortest distance from triangle to point in 2D space?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a triangle with three corners located at $(-6,7), (2,5)$ and $(-4,8)$. I need to calculate shortest distance from nearest edge of triangle to the point $(-4,7)$. I can't figure out how to do that, could I have some advise?

Comment: you should draw it out and see which side of the triangle is closest to the point, and then use the shortest distance between a point and a line

Comment: Definitely possible, but I need to solve it algebrally (eg. by calculating).

Comment: The point seems inside the triangle. So what do you mean shortest distance from the triangle? From the vertices or from edges?

Comment: From the edges, sorry for confusion.

Comment: You simply need to [calculate the distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) between the point and the edges and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the equations of the 3 lines that make the triangle:
$$m = \frac {y_2-y_1} {x_2-x_1} \\ y - y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
Then you can simplify, and use [this formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) to find distance between $(-4,7)$ and each line, for a line of equation $ax+by+c=0$:
$$\operatorname{distance}= \frac {ax+by+c} {\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks, pretty sure I solved it.